# Ambiguous JSON data extraction

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Maybe someone here has done this before and has the secret sauce preventing me from having to re-invent the wheel.
I'm just not finding anythign that satisfies the ambiguous & dynamic nature of this effort.

Below I'm trying to fill-in the body of `myDynamicValuesExtractionMethod()`.

If possible, `js` should be thought could have any various structure.  For instance don't count on the metadata like `totalItems` be present.  Perhaps a different `spec` will require a value extracted from a object contained in a different json `logKey` object. ...
But a value given to `spec` has to be constructed with awareness of the matched json structure by the end user.
`spec` is a dynamic configured value set once by the end user and paired to it's applied json data source.

This is in a C# app.

There is not anything spelled out as to what syntax `spec` must use.
So re-scoping the syntax of `spec` is open to any helpful remarks.
What is shown is just my first thought.

In the given example the desired return would be (447006, 447005, 446991, 447004, 446999, 446981, 446983)
At this time expect the returned value is always a list of strings.

Is there a different library I should be use that already does this?

Is there a Linq expression or an .eval() that will get my values?

Is there a Web service I should consider passing the work to?

```
/* ---------------------------------------------*/
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            String spec = "lobKeys[].lobKey";
            JObject j = JObject.Parse(js);

            List<String> vals = myDynamicValuesExtractionMethod(j, spec);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        private static List<String> myDynamicValuesExtractionMethod(JObject j, string spec) {
            List<String> ret = new List<string>();

            return ret;
        }


        static readonly String js = @"
{
  ""totalItems"" : 7
  , ""lobKeys"" : [
      { ""lobKey"" : ""447006"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-13"" }
    , { ""lobKey"" : ""447005"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-14"" }
    , { ""lobKey"" : ""446991"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-15"" }
    , { ""lobKey"" : ""447004"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-16"" }
    , { ""lobKey"" : ""446999"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-17"" }
    , { ""lobKey"" : ""446981"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-18"" }
    , { ""lobKey"" : ""446983"", ""updatedAt"" : ""2018-11-19"" }
  ]
}";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it looks like you have already found a solution, I just wanted to mention that you can do what you want using Json.Net with the [`JToken.SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) method.  It supports [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) syntax, which is similar in concept to JmesPath.

```
JToken j = JToken.Parse(js);
string spec = "lobKeys[*].lobKey";
List<string> vals = j.SelectTokens(spec).Values<string>().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vals));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G7qTqQ

You can also use Linq methods to do the same thing:

```
JToken j = JToken.Parse(js);
List<string> vals = j["lobKeys"].Select(t => t["lobKey"]).Values<string>().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vals));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JZCj5D

Comment: What is JObject j is "[ { "bla": bla1 }, { "bla": bla2 }, { "bla": bla3 } ]" an anonymous list
How does the `spec` look?

Comment: In that case the spec would be `[*].bla`, but note you cannot use `JObject.Parse` because the JSON represents an array not an object.  If you need to handle both you should use `JToken.Parse` instead.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6W3yx

Comment: You win.  I'd much rather use the tools that already exist in the project (NewtonSoft) over adding in something new.  Plus the `.ToList()` make my end solution a little bit easier over taking JmseSoft returned json string and then making a list out of it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out JmesPath.org appears to be the perfect (so far) answer.  It satisfies my three test cases & one (so far) use case.